# Create bulleted list in iOS Mail

Tags: iphone, ipad, email, mail.app

Is it possible to create a bulleted or numbered list in Mail on an iDevice? If so, please share how. I know it'll display them. Like if I create it in GMail on my MacBook, save a draft, then open it on the device, I see the bullets as intended, but I would like to actually create this same thing on my iPad/ iPhone.

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Apple offers the ability to add some basic controls (eg. bold, etc.) on the iPhone/iPad (without the keyboard) it's not possible without copying and pasting from a previous message.

You could create a draft with the different types of list to copy and paste and use that.

Of note: some third party apps can help with this: eg. [MarkdownMail](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/markdownmail/) just released today by Second Gear Software ($1.99) or any other app that will allow you to create HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a hack, but one thing you can do is compose your message in a note, which does support bulleted lists, then copy the message into the email app. It really surprises me that this feature doesn’t exist.